# How to list items in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a list of `<a>`s like this:

```
<tr>
    <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
    <td>
        <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
function countryList(string) {
  let pattern = new RegExp('^.+\/wiki\/'); // adjust `RegExp`
  countryListLinks = string.replace(pattern, '');
}
```

I tried this but I get nothing:

```
  countryLinks.each(function(){
    console.log(countryList);
  });
```

I tried this but I only get one item and the other `undefined`

```
countryLinks.forEach(countryList);
```

I am trying to output each `href` but without `/wiki/` individually so that I can use them:

```
Geum_River Korea
```

Comment: Is this in Node or in the browser?

Comment: @trincot just trying using jsFiddle with js and jQuery, nothing else so i guess its the browser

Comment: Is the HTML stored in a variable, or is it the current document where your script is running?

Comment: @trincot it's in the actual doc not a var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let word = '/wiki/';
$('[href]').map(function(i, e) {
  var href = $(e).attr('href');
  console.log(href.substring(href.indexOf(word) + word.length, href.length));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
  <td>
    <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` function

```js
function countryList(string) {
  let pattern = new RegExp('^.+\/wiki\/'); // adjust `RegExp`
  return string.replace(pattern, '');
}

var result = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).map(function(a){return a.href}).map(countryList);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<tr>
    <th style="padding-right:1em">Location</th>
    <td>
        <span class="location">Lower reaches of the <a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: nice but I need to output them individually

Comment: actually adding the "individually" request on the answer to make it clearer for future

Comment: @rob.m what do you mean "individually"?

Comment: I need to save each of them in a unique variable or into something that I can call individually

Comment: You can address array elements individually, @rob.m: `result[0]`, `result[1]`, ...

Comment: that will be like `results[0]` or `results[1]` right? But in reality I don't know how many I have so it will be difficult if not impossible for me to call them with `[]` unless there is a dynamic way which i am missing out

Comment: Use `foreach` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @rob.m why do you need cal them `[]` separatelly? what are you going to do with strings?

Comment: Wut? What you're asking makes no sense. That's how you 'create variables to call individually'. It'd be your job to find the index of the object you need.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet ok i see

Comment: @MaximKuzmin with each of them I would then call an `api` with that `string` as a `search parameter` in my case

Comment: @DazDylz is it not the foreach what i tried as per my question?

Comment: @rob.m do it in for/foreach loop

Comment: @MaximKuzmin ok I give it a try now

Comment: @rob.m foreach(var s in strings) { api.call(s); }

Answer (score 0):

follow this simple code and then parse using replace method

```
$('.location').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```